# Is there a way to generate melodies in specific key by fine-tuning MusicVAE model

Tags: vue.js, magenta

I wanted to know if it was possible to fine-tune the options of the magenta MusicVAE or MusicRNN model to produce melodies of a specific key.

Looked through the code and saw a MusicVAESpec object and a MusicVAEControlArgs object to help with the fine-tuning but I just don't know how to configure it.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Find below the code for the function I am working on. I have initialized a MusicVAESpec object and passed it as a parameter when initializing the MusicVAE model. Also have a MUsicVAEControlArgs object that is passed to model.sample() but I get a
"Error: Error in matMul: inner shapes (1382) and (1370) of Tensors with shapes 1,1382 and 1370,4096 and transposeA=false and transposeB=false must match."

§

```
 async generateMelody() {

      this.isLoading = true;

     

      const VAEspec = {
        "type": "MusicVAE",
        "dataConverter": {
          "type": "MelodyConverter",
          "args": {
            "numSteps": 16,
            "minPitch": 21,
            "maxPitch": 108,
            "ignorePolyphony": true,
          }
        },
        "useBooleanDecoder": false,
        "conditionOnKey": true
      }

      const model = new mm.MusicVAE('https://storage.googleapis.com/magentadata/js/checkpoints/music_vae/mel_4bar_med_lokl_q2', VAEspec);
      const mrnnModel = new mm.MusicRNN('https://storage.googleapis.com/magentadata/js/checkpoints/music_rnn/melody_rnn');

      await model.initialize()
      await mrnnModel.initialize()
      const temperature = Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.6;

      const controlArgs = {
        key: 60,
      };
      const samples = await model.sample(1, temperature, controlArgs);
      console.log(samples)
      

      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  },
}
```